# Starting Settings Activity for result

Tags: android, android-intent, android-location

In my application I'm checking whether the GPS is enabled on the user's device, and if not I would like to send him to the Settings to let him turn it on.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(intent, LocationHelper.LOCATION_SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE);
```

After the user closes Settings screen, I would to perform an action right inside the `onActivityResult()`.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == LocationHelper.LOCATION_SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE) {
        LogUtils.d("onActivityResult from settings");
        fetchCurrentLocation();
    }
}
```

However, the `onActivityResult()` doesn't get called. Am I doing something wrong or this approach doesn't work in general? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

lauch the setting intent :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

and fetch the current location in onResume method :

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(isGPSEnabled){
         fetchCurrentLocation();
}
}
```

after backing from setting screen , your onResume method will be call and here you can fetch your location.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I'm actually using this approach now, cause I haven't found a better solution. Just thought there exists an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

`Enable GPS` programmatically using the following code,

```
private void askToEnableGPS(){
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(10 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(2 * 1000);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

    SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
    settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull @NotNull Exception e) {
                    int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                    switch (statusCode) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            try {
                                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the
                                // result in onActivityResult().
                                ResolvableApiException rae = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                rae.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, 5678);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sie) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            String errorMessage = "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be " +
                                    "fixed here. Fix in Settings.";
                            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
                            // notify user
                            new androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(MainActivity.this,
                                    R.style.Theme_MaterialComponents_DayNight_DarkActionBar)).setMessage("Please enable location services").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Open location settings", (dialog, which) -> {
                                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                            }).create().show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

And get the results in `onActivityResult` with Request Code `5678`.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 5678  && resultCode  == RESULT_OK) {
            // GPS Enabled
        }
}
```

Comment: @Egor, Please try this.

Answer (score -2):

Have you defined ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Yes, I have, otherwise I would have got an exception.

Comment: what's the value of LocationHelper.LOCATION_SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE ?

Comment: It's 16, but does it matter?

Comment: Yes.. requestCode  If >= 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity exits.